# NOT NULL constraint failed: accounts_myuser.password

Tags: django, django-forms, modelform, notnull

I am doing a web application in django where users can create accounts. I'm storing the users' passwords in plaintext as authentication in my system does not totally depend on password but also on the otp. The problem I'm facing all of a sudden(it worked fine earlier) at the POST request of registration, is "NOT NULL constraint failed: accounts_myuser.password". I tried deleting database and migrations and re-migrated but it didn't help. I'm giving the ModelForm and the Model(custom one) below.I've only two fields namely 'email' and 'username' described in my model. It worked fine and I could register users successfully earlier with the code below. Could anyone please help me?

## forms.py

```
class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    password1 = forms.IntegerField(label='Password', min_value=0000, max_value=9999, widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    password2 = forms.IntegerField(label='Password Confirmation', min_value=0000, max_value=9999,
                                   widget=forms.PasswordInput)


    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email']

    def clean_password1(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords do not match!")
        if len(str(password1)) != 4 or len(str(password2)) != 4:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords should be of length Four!")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.password = self.cleaned_data['password1']

        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

## models.py

```
class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, username, email, password=None):

        if not email:

            raise ValueError('Users must have an email')

        user = self.model(
                    username = username,
                    email = self.normalize_email(email),
                    password = password
                )

        # user.set_password(password)

        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user


    def create_superuser(self, username, email, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
                username, email, password
                )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

Comment: Why are you showing your manager instead of your model? Are you using `create_user` or `create_superuser` at all? Because, if you pass a null password to any of the two method, this error would trigger.

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues yes, that's what the problem was! None was being generated and passed as the password! Really sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: Ok, I will write a proper answer In a moment

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues Thanks a bunch! but I solved it when I realized where I was going wrong!

Comment: Sure, but here in StackOverflow we always try to have the questions properly answered, so when people with the same problem search for it on internet, they can easily see the solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call the methods `create_user` or `create_superuser`, are you passing valid values for the `password` keyword?

Because, if you pass a null password (`None`) to any of the two method, this would definitely throw a 
"NOT NULL constraint failed" error on the passwerod field.

Answer (score 2):

TLDR; 
add **`password`** field to `fields` of  Meta class as

```
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'email', 'password']
```

If you doesn't add the field to **`fields`**, Django won't take/accept data from the `form`

Answer (score 0):

1. delete save() method
2. refresh page
3. add data (its will not adding in db)
4. sumbit data
5. add save() method again

Answer (score 0):

Check through which method you have submitted your form. If your method is POST then write a proper code in views.py to listen that request.