# django: not null constraint failed

Tags: django

I am getting "not null constraint failed" exception for password field in my custom user model while registering a user through the browser(ModelForm) but I can add that user through django shell successfully. I've tried deleting database and migrations and re-doing it. Any idea why this is happening? I'd be really thankful for the help!

Comment: How is this different from [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52237758/9225671) ? Did the solution work that a user provided there?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NOT NULL constraint failed: accounts\_myuser.password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52237758/not-null-constraint-failed-accounts-myuser-password)

Comment: @Ralf No that solution doesn't work. And yes this is the same question as that one. And can that solution really work? because from what i know that we can just set_password(). How can I add that field in the Meta class as it is not defined in the User model.

Comment: If you don't like an answer in your question you should make it clear and wait for a better answer for that question, not make a duplicate. Please take the [tour] and learn [ask]

Answer (score 0):

You must create a `migration`, where you will specify default value for a new field, since you don't want it to be null. If null is not required, simply add `null=True` and create and run migration.

Comment: how can you specify that for a password field in user model? I've a custom user model and we can just set_password @Shubhendu Yadav And done with the migration thing, but if you could please look at my previous question,you'd get it. It's the same question.

Comment: try deleting the database and then makemigration and then migrate